# How can I enable RTL(Right to Left) in textAngular editor?

Tags: angularjs, textangular

I'm using textAngular as text editor in one of my projects. We have to support Hebrew and hence we have to enable RTL by default for Hebrew users.

Is there any configuration settings in textAngular for that ? 
I know I can do that by directly placing "direction:rtl" attribute in both div and text areas. But I would like to see if there is a default settings available to use instead.

I don't see any specific thread discussing the same in stack overflow.
Please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no any default support for `rtl` in `textAngular`.

And according to this [Bug Report](https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/issues/70) collaborators are not going to implement it.